# is a bad idea insert the request in the builtin dictionary?

Tags: python, django

A lot of time you need the request in a form or in a util function etc...

Is a bad idea insert the request in the builtin dictionary?

That is to say, is a bad idea implement a middleware like this?:

```
import sys
PY3 = False
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    PY3 = True


class GlobalRequestMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if PY3:
            import builtins
            builtins.__dict__["request_global"] = request
        else:
            import __builtin__
            __builtin__.__dict__["request_global"] = request
```

Then you can use the request in a form or in a util function, something like this:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super(MyModelForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.owner = request_global.user
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Or

```
def my_func_util():
    if request_global.user.is_anonymous():
        XXX
    else:
        YYY
```

I understand that "always" is better explicit that implicit... but is there some reason more??

Comment: Because multi-threading.

Comment: I have multi-thread but I think that this is not a problem. A request only is executing in a thread...

Comment: Yes, and setting the request object as a builtin global is not thread safe.

Comment: Then, if I set the request object as a builtin, is the request object global to every thread?

Comment: You're creating a global variable, with all the usual problems (thread safety being one of them but far from the only one), and to top it off you confuse every reader by hiding it.

Comment: @Goin: yes, builtins are not isolated per thread.

Comment: And could I create a global variable, but only accesible in this thread?

Comment: Possibly, but that wouldn't solve any of the other problems. Just bite the bullet and be explicit.

Comment: "Is it a bad idea to modify `__builtins__`?" - Yes, absolutely. On a scale between "I created getters and setters for simple attributes" and "my whole program is written as a single 300-line list comprehension", I'd say it's about as bad as "I use exec to create and read variables dynamically because I don't like dictionaries".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is a bad idea definitely